# Close button is not showing up in a pop out menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a website where I need to show a pop out menu. When I click the menu bar, it shows the navigation page or menu page. Below is the HTML code

```
<header class="header cd-header">
<div class="cd-primary-nav-trigger" href="#0">

        <div class="buttons-header active ">
        <div class="nav menu right small-1 column">
        <span class=" icon-container">
            <span class="line line01"></span>
            <span class="line line02"></span>
            <span class="line line03"></span>
            <span class="line line04"></span>
        </span>
     </div>
       </div>
    </div><!-- cd-primary-nav-trigger -->
</header>`
```

**CSS :**

```
.menu {
margin-top: -4.5em!important;
width: 68px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 /* height: 22%;*/
}
.cd-primary-nav-trigger {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
width: 93px;
height: 65px;
position: relative;
right: 2%;

}
.nav .icon-container {
width: 93px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 0;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.nav .line {
position: absolute;
left: 65px;
right: 28px;
height: 3px;
background-color: #0079dd;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.active .nav .line {
left: 28px;
}
.cd-primary-nav-trigger.nav .line01  {
top: 0;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition-delay: 210ms;
-moz-transition-delay: 210ms;
-ms-transition-delay: 210ms;
-o-transition-delay: 210ms;
transition-delay: 210ms;
position: relative;
left: 70%;
bottom: auto;
right: auto;
width: 27px;
height: 3px;
background-color: #0079dd;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
transition: background-color 0.3s;
transition-delay: 210ms;
transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav .line02 {
top: 7px;
-webkit-transition-delay: 140ms;
-moz-transition-delay: 140ms;
-ms-transition-delay: 140ms;
-o-transition-delay: 140ms;
transition-delay: 140ms;
}
.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav .line03 {
top: 14px;
-webkit-transition-delay: 70ms;
-moz-transition-delay: 70ms;
-ms-transition-delay: 70ms;
-o-transition-delay: 70ms;
transition-delay: 70ms;
}
.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav .line04 {
top: 21px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0ms;
-moz-transition-delay: 0ms;
-ms-transition-delay: 0ms;
-o-transition-delay: 0ms;
transition-delay: 0ms;
}
.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav:hover .line {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-7px,0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(0,-7px,0);
-ms-transform:translate3d(0,-7px,0);
-o-transform:translate3d(0,-7px,0);
transform:translate3d(0,-7px,0);
}

.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav:hover .line01 {
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition-delay:0;
-moz-transition-delay:0;
-ms-transition-delay:0;
-o-transition-delay:0;
transition-delay:0;
}

.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav:hover .line02 {
-webkit-transition-delay:70ms;
-moz-transition-delay:70ms;
-ms-transition-delay:70ms;
-o-transition-delay:70ms;
transition-delay:70ms;
}

.cd-primary-nav-trigger.nav:hover .line03 {
-webkit-transition-delay:140ms;
-moz-transition-delay:140ms;
-ms-transition-delay:140ms;
-o-transition-delay:140ms;
transition-delay:140ms;
}

.cd-primary-nav-trigger .nav:hover .line04 {
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition-delay:210ms;
-moz-transition-delay:210ms;
-ms-transition-delay:210ms;
-o-transition-delay:210ms;
transition-delay:210ms;
}

.cd-header {
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
transition: background-color 0.3s;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
.cd-header.is-fixed {
    /* when the user scrolls down, we hide the header right above the viewport */
position: fixed;
top: -60px!important;
background-color: #fff;
opacity: 0.95;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s;
  }
 .cd-header.is-visible {
    /* if the user changes the scrolling direction, we show the header */
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  .cd-header.menu-is-open {
    /* add a background color to the header when the navigation is open */
background-color:  #002a67 solid;
  }

.navigation-wrapper {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#002a67, #0079dd); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#002a67, #0079dd); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#002a67, #0079dd); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#002a67, #0079dd); /* Standard syntax */
padding: 40px 0 0 0;
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: none;
}

.navigation {
  padding: 20px 5% 0 5%;
  display: none;
}
.show-menu {
  display: block;
}


.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 50px 0;

} 
.navigation li.small-padding {
  margin: 0;
  }

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 1%;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 150%;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
   -webkit-transition: .4s linear; 
    -moz-transition: .4s linear; 
    transition: .4s linear;
  opacity: 0.95;
  -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 5%;
  border-left: 3px solid #eee;
}

.cd-header {

  top: 0%!important;
  left: 0;
  width:100vw;
  z-index: 2000;
  box-shadow: 0 -11px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.cd-primary-nav-trigger .icon-container.is-clicked {
  background-color: transparent;

}

.icon-container.is-clicked .line03 , .icon-container.is-clicked .line01  {
  background-color: #fff;
  top:47px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

    .cd-primary-nav-trigger {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 30px;
    top: 80%;
    left:90%;
    bottom: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .cd-primary-nav-trigger .icon-container {
    left: auto;
    right: 0em;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
  }

  .cd-primary-nav {
  /* by default it's hidden - on top of the viewport */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#00003b, #0079dd); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#00003b, #0079dd); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#00003b, #0079dd); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#00003b, #0079dd); /* Standard syntax */
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  opacity: .95;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* this fixes the buggy scrolling on webkit browsers - mobile devices only - when overflow property is applied */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.cd-primary-nav.is-visible{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.icon-container.is-clicked .line:nth-child(3) {
   top: 31px;
   height: 3px;
   width: 22px;
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.icon-container.is-clicked .line:nth-child(1){
   top: 31px;
   height: 3px;
   width: 22px;
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.cd-primary-nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 2vw 0 0 0;
}
.cd-primary-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "museo_sans900";
  font-weight: 500;
  display: table;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 8px -17px;
  width: 100vw;
  vertical-align: middle;


}
.cd-primary-nav a {
  color: #fff;


}
 .cd-primary-nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100vw!important;
  color: #0079dd;
  display: inline-block;
}


.cd-primary-nav.is-visible {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
  .icon-container.is-clicked .line03 , .icon-container.is-clicked .line01  {
  background-color: #fff;
  top:47px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;

}
```

**Javascript is:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var MQL = 1170;

    //primary navigation slide-in effect
    if($(window).width() > MQL) {
        var headerHeight = $('.cd-header').height();
        $(window).on('scroll',
        {
            previousTop: 0
        }, 
        function () {
            var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            //check if user is scrolling up
            if (currentTop < this.previousTop ) {
                //if scrolling up...
                if (currentTop > 0 && $('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
                    $('.cd-header').addClass('is-visible');
                    $('.line').css("background-color","#fff");
                    $('#logo').attr("src","images/logo_white.png").css("margin-top","-9%");

                } else {
                    $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
                    $('#logo').attr("src","images/logo.png");
                    $('.line').css("background-color","#0079dd");

                }


            } else {
                //if scrolling down...
                $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible');
                if( currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.cd-header').addClass('is-fixed');
            }

            this.previousTop = currentTop;
        });
    }




    //open/close primary navigation
    $('.cd-primary-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
        $('.icon-container').toggleClass('is-clicked'); 
        $('.nav').toggleClass('menu-is-open');
        $('.nav').toggleClass('is-clicked');
        $('.logo').toggleClass('hidden');


        //in firefox transitions break when parent overflow is changed, so we need to wait for the end of the trasition to give the body an overflow hidden
        if( $('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible') ) {

            $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
                $('.icon-container').addClass('is-visible');
                $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');

            });
        } else {
            $('.cd-primary-nav').addClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
                $('.is-fixed').toggleClass('hidden');
                $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

When I click the menu bars, I can see the menu navigation page, however, close button does not show up at the corner of the page.

Please help me!

Comment: I think you and I can agree that this is way too much code. Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code and only post the relevant part of your code here?

Comment: I see no <button> or <input> tags in your code. Are they supposed to be in the <span>?